# Python + JSON, what happened to None?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Dumping and loading a dict with [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None) as key, results in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with `'null'` as the key.

Values are un-affected, but things get even worse if a string-key `'null'` actually exists.

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I serialize/deserialize a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with `None` keys?

## Example

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({'123':None, None:'What happened to None?'}))
{u'123': None, u'null': u'What happened to None?'}
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({'123':None, None:'What happened to None?', 'null': 'boom'}))
{u'123': None, u'null': u'boom'}
```

Comment: Btw output of the second code seems to have been fiddled with.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

JSON objects are maps of *strings* to values.  If you try to use another type of key, they'll get converted to strings.

```
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({123: None}))
{'123': None}
>>> json.loads(json.dumps({None: None}))
{'null': None}
```

Answer (score 22):

According to the [specification](http://www.json.org/), `None` is not a valid key. It would amount to a JSON object expression, which looks like

```
{ ..., null: ..., ... }
```

which is not valid (i.e., cannot be generated using the syntax diagram.)

Arguably, the JSON module should have raised an exception upon serialization instead of silently generating a string representation of the value.

**EDIT** Just saw, that the behaviour of the module is [documented](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#basic-usage) (somewhat implicitly):

> If skipkeys is True (default: False), then dict keys that are not of a basic type (str, unicode, int, long, float, bool, None) will be skipped instead of raising a TypeError.

so it seems, as if this behaviour is intentional (I still find it questionable given the current JSON specification).

Comment: skipKeys does not have an effect on the observed behavior.
"None" is a basic type so skipKeys=True would not cause a "skipping" just as skipKeys=False does not cause a TypeError.

I would have liked a small note in the documentation, something like: "For reversible encoding, only use strings as keys."

Answer (score 5):

As @dan04 shows, `None` is converted to `'null'`.

Everything is fine, the value is stored into the dict with

```py
"null": "What happened to None?"
```

But then came another Key called `'null'`.

So the old value of the None/`'null'`-Key (`"What happened to None?"`) is overwritten with `"boom"`.